# data of dataGrid in SonataAdmin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I try to get the value of a field I configure in my class that extends Admin in function configureFormFields.
I want to attach it as a parameter for custom action I created.
any idea how to fetch it? I want to change 'test' to a value according to a field in a row in the admin.

The Admin code

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list) {
    $list ->add('_action','actions',array('actions' => array('run' => array('template' => 'AcmePortalBundle:Files:action.html.twig'), ))) 
        ->addIdentifier('name') 
        ->add('serverPath'); }
```

The twig template action.html.twig

```
{ % if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('edit') % } 
<a href="{{ path('upload', {'t': 'test' }) }}"> 
  <img src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataadmin/famfamfam/server_connect.png') }}" /> 
</a>
{ % endif % }
```

Comment: Any bunch of code for us maybe from your admin class?

Comment: <code>class FilesSettingAdmin extends Admin{

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list) 
    {
        $list
            ->add('_action','actions',array('actions' => array('run' => array('template' => 'AcmePortalBundle:Files:action.html.twig'), )))
            ->addIdentifier('name')
            ->add('serverPath');
    }

The action.html.twig
{ % if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('edit') % }
<a href="{{ path('upload', {'t': 'test' }) }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataadmin/famfamfam/server_connect.png') }}"  />

</a>
{ % endif % }</code>

Comment: in the TWIG I want to replace 'test' in <a href with the value of the name field in the dashboard.

Comment: By "a bunch of code" I meant in your original post, by editing it Sela!

Comment: sorry edit my original message. i didn't notice it didn't format it as a code in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datagrid value is in in variable "value" :)
Extend base list field and use value in template. Don't forget to test empty value

```
{% extends admin.getTemplate('base_list_field') %}

{% block field%}
    {%- if value is empty -%}
    &nbsp; //or something other
    {%- else -%}
        <a href="{{ path('upload', {'t': value }) }}"> 
        ....
    {%- endif -%}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I found a solution that I would post as a reply to my original, but your answer actually answered what I asked. I decided at the end to pass the ID instead of the var name.
One thing probably I wasn't clear, I want to change the route of the action. Which template should I use for that? as I can't find base_action_field twig file.

Comment: Template for base_list_field is in \vendor\sonata-project\admin-bundle\Sonata\AdminBundle\Resources\views\CRUD\base_list_field.html.twig (Sonata v 2.1)